# How to stop IntelliJ from hiding characters in code

Tags: intellij-idea

I am writing some velocity code, where all of the keywords are prefixed by the '#' character. When IntelliJ displays the code, it removes the '#' and bolds the keyword. How do I get IntelliJ to keep the '#' character.

See

[image: screenshot]

All of the `if` and `end` keywords should actually be `#if` and `#end`.

Similarly, when editing a Java file, in the escape sequences (e.g. '\n', '\t'), the '\' is removed and the escape sequence is bolded. I'd like to keep the '\'.

Comment: Did you install any third-party plug-ins? It [doesn't happen](https://i.imgur.com/hEI2CNp.png) for me in Java files.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IDE fixed the problem. I guess this was a bug and not a feature.